# Shader Editor: sticky header while moving nodes?

Tags: node-editor, interface, shaders

It seems that Blender UI designers decided that whenever the user moves anything, the UI needs to change to display some kind of information, even if it is completely useless.

In the Shader Editor, if I move a node, the Header changes to "Auto Offset set to right" and displays the current XY coordinates, down to *four decimal places*! This is unnecessary, super distracting, and the opposite of helpful.

Is there a way for me to tell the Shader Editor to stop doing this? Just simply display the Header, don't display any of this coordinate information.

I can't hide the Header entirely; I need it for menus. I just want it to settle down and stop distracting me with garbage data in my face whenever I move anything.

Thanks

Aaron

Comment: Short answer: No, part of the grab/move operator. It's might be possible to overrride the draw and invoke methods but I don't think that's worth it...

Comment: Wow. Some admin actually censored my message. I've never seen such control freak behavior on any board. I've seen fanboys and fangirls who can't accept that there may be design issues with their favorite product, but I have not seen my messages edited like this. I guess the Ban Hammer is poised and ready to smite me.

Comment: This is a wrong place to writing this. Post your observations in the devtalk forum: https://devtalk.blender.org/ This site is for questions only, so this post should be closed.

Comment: This is neither a board nor a regular forum, it's a Q&A site driven by volunteers trying to help other Blender users. We suggest edits to questions and answers all the time in order to make them more useful and remove extraneous content like your personal opinion to something which is superfluous to solve any problem. If that bothers you, try https://blenderartists.org/ instead. Recommend take the [tour] to learn about how this site works and start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are just too many Blender sites, it's confusing. But OK.